# LotusScript ans Two dimensional Array & subscription out or range error

Tags: arrays, vba, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Hello I have two dimensional array as below in LotusScript.

```
Counter = 0
While Not (ProcessingViewDoc Is Nothing )
    Redim Preserve AllRecrods(Counter,0)  
    AllRecrods(Counter,0)   = ProcessingViewDoc.Test1(0)
    Redim Preserve AllRecrods(Counter,1)  
    AllRecrods(Counter,1)   = ProcessingViewDoc.Test2(0)
    Redim Preserve AllRecrods(Counter,2)  

    Set ProcessingViewDoc  = ProcessingView.GetNextDocument(ProcessingViewDoc)
    Counter = Counter +1
Wend
```

When It processes next document it does and reaches to counter 1 and second document it gives me error subscription out of range.
Here is global declaration of array.

```
Dim AllRecrods() As Variant
```

Here is the line when it gives error when it goes to loop second time.

```
Redim Preserve AllRecrods(Counter,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Richard's excellent answer, I would suggest a couple of things.

1) Instead of `While Not (ProcessingViewDoc Is Nothing)` (which contains two negatives, making it harder to read), use `Do Until doc Is Nothing`. It is much clearer.

2) If you use a list, you don't have to worry about redim of the array. You could make it a list of a custom data type, and if you use the UNID of the document as the key, you can quickly connect the values back to the originating document.

My code would look something like this:

```
--- Declarations ---
Type recordData
    value1 As String
    value2 As String
End Type


--- Main Code ---
Dim allRecords List As recordData
Dim unid as String
Do Until ProcessingViewDoc Is Nothing 
    unid = ProcessingViewDoc.UniqueID
    allRecords(unid).value1 = ProcessingViewDoc.Test1(0)
    allRecords(unid).value2 = ProcessingViewDoc.Test2(0)
    Set ProcessingViewDoc  = ProcessingView.GetNextDocument(ProcessingViewDoc)
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using ReDim with the Preserve option and changing both of the dimensions. You can't do that.

From the [documentation for the ReDim statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fr/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_REDIM_STATEMENT.html):

> If Preserve is specified, you can change only the upper bound of the
>   last array dimension. Attempting to change any other bound results in
>   an error.

Also, the logic there is screwed up. You're doing three redims on every iteration, with the first one shrinking the second dimension back to zero on every iteration. Even if you weren't changing the first dimension, that would lose the data that you stored in AllRecrods( n ,1) because the preserve option can't keep data in a dimension that you shrink below the size that you've already used!

You should probably consider swapping your two dimensions, reversing them in your assignments, keeping the first dimension constant at 2, and eliminating two of your ReDim Preserve statements. I.e., just do one `ReDim Preserve AllRecrods(2,counter)` on each iteration of the loop.